# Php, simple locking against all request to have one

Tags: php

I have a big cron (rebuild a cache) which requires to exclude all other request and hold them or stop them. So only one request should be running at one time.

Can this work out?

```
$f = fopen("lockfile", 'w+');
if (flock($f, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB))
{
    sleep(10); // doing the work
}
else
{
    echo 'Come back later!';
}
```

may this work, even for Windows and Linux? No concurrencing threads then?

Comment: Read the warnings at http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php . It won't work on FAT file systems or in the same process but different threads (e.g. FPM and apache worker in some OSs whatever that means)

Comment: ok, FAT doesnt bothers me and I cant call the same process at the same time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's really necessary to block clients while the cache is rebuilding, avoid the file locks and just create a file during maintenance, have the clients check for it, and delete it when done.

**cron.php**

```
<?php
//..
touch('/path/to/lockfile.dat');
//.. do work
unlink('/path/to/lockfile.dat');
```

**other clients**

```
<?php

if (file_exists('/path/to/lockfile.dat')) {
    die('Under maintenance, please check back shortly.');
}
```

Comment: @JohnSmith you can put this inside a ram disc, then you have no I/O and as fast as possible

Comment: There's no need for real "thread safety" here.  If the file exists, maintenance is in progress, if not, then things are normal.  Plus if dozens of requests are trying to fopen the file when it's not locked will just result in tons of useless file opens and closes stepping all over eachother.

Comment: and what if cron.php dies? lockfile.dat will remain then

Comment: If it's written properly it shouldn't die; only a fatal error, time limit, or memory limit should kill it.  If you know roughly how long it takes to clear the cache, set up a cron to follow to delete the lock file after a period of time just in case the cron fails to do so.